# Split list according to condition, apply function to sublists, and combine in original order in Python

Tags: python

I have a list containing different kinds of elements. I need to split the list according to their kind in sublists (here starting with 'a' or 'b', so 2 sublists).

```
l = ['a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b2', 'b3']
```

Then these sublists are processed separately. The result of the processing (e.g. a remote call to a server) are again two lists with the same length. I only want to make 2 calls instead of `n=len(l)` calls as this is much less expensive.

Next, I have to put these lists back together according to the original order.

```
# original list
l = ['a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b2', 'b3']
# sublists which need to be processed separately
sl1 = [item for item in l if item.startswith('a')]
sl2 = [item for item in l if not item.startswith('a')]
# expensive call to server
f1 = lambda l: [x + '_calc1' for x in l ]
f2 = lambda l: [x + '_calc2' for x in l ]

sr1 = f1(sl1)
sr2 = f2(sl2)

# rebuild list according to original order
a = iter(sr1)
b = iter(sr2)
l_result = [next(a) if x.startswith('a') else next(b) for x in l]
# >> ['a1_calc1', 'b1_calc2', 'a2_calc1', 'a3_calc1', 'b2_calc2', 'b3_calc2']
```

The way I currently do it feels very clumsy and I hope there is 'pythonic' way to do these split-apply-combine.

Comment: Do you have control over the response of the remote call or is it an external call?

Comment: It is in external call. I know the response is again a list of the same length as the list i pass to the external call.

Comment: And what exactly looks wrong for you? Actually you spend 2 lines for split (and they are very clear), and 3 lines for join (one of which is difficult to read, but still OK). The only thing which isn't good, is that you repeat the split condition 3 times in the code, it's better to put it to separate function `def check_condition(x): x.startswith('a')`

Comment: Is there any clue in the results as to source of information? That is do the results really contain the source, like: `x + '_calc1'`? Or are the results more like `hash(x)`, but the order of the results is the same as the source list?

Comment: @quamrana: it is like hash(x). Just the order is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate, may be a little less clumsy (PS. I have written down a skeleton, you can make it more readable by adding functions or a class with proper methods

```
l = original_list

type_1 = [(i, x) for i,x in enumerate(l) if condition_type_1(x)]
type_2 = [(i, x) for i,x in enumerate(l) if condition_type_2(x)]

response_1 = server_request_1([x[1] for x in type_1])
response_2 = server_request_2([x[1] for x in type_2])

response_1 = [(tp[0], resp) for tp, resp in zip(type_1, response_1)]
response_2 = [(tp[0], resp) for tp, resp in zip(type_2, response_2)]

response = response_1 + response_2
response = sorted(response, key=lambda k:k[0])
response = [x[1] for x in response]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can keep the original indexes of the positions in `l`, you can slot the results back into a new list:

```py
l = ['a1', 'b1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b2', 'b3']

e = [(idx,item) for (idx,item) in enumerate(l)]
sl1 = [item for item in e if item[1].startswith('a')]
sl2 = [item for item in e if not item[1].startswith('a')]

# expensive call to server
f1 = lambda l: [x[1] + '_calc1' for x in l ]
f2 = lambda l: [x[1] + '_calc2' for x in l ]

sr1 = f1(sl1)
sr2 = f2(sl2)

l_result = [None] * len(l)
for idx,item in enumerate(sr1):
    idx,_ = sl1[idx]
    l_result[idx] = item
    
for idx,item in enumerate(sr2):
    idx,_ = sl2[idx]
    l_result[idx] = item

print(l_result)
```